# Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'i386'

Tags: iphone, streaming, ffmpeg

I downloaded this sample project (http://tunein.com/mobile/ios/tunein_radio_source.zip), but when compiling, I am getting in the ffmpeg library this error:

Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'armv7'

Even when changing to LLVM, I am getting the exact same error.

Any suggestion?

Meir

Comment: See this post   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383714/xcode-4-2-issue-standard-armv7][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383714/xcode-4-2-issue-standard-armv7

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I Tried all solution (except downgrading), But it didn't helped.

Comment: Try "Validate Settings" in Target and Project Settings

Answer (score 22):

xcode build errors:

```
Unsupported compiler ‘GCC 4.2′ selected for architecture ‘i386′
```

Solution:

This can be caused by importing a project for a pre- iOS 5 SDK into a copy of xcode with iOS 5 SDK only.

To fix,

> Click your Project -> Build Settings.  Then under Build Options, there
>   is an entry for Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C.  Choose Apple LLVM
>   compiler 3.0.

There is a chance this could effect other aspects of your binaries as you are using a new compiler, so  YMMV.  That being said, it’s so far caused no issues for me.

Answer (score 4):

select the LLVM compiler under "Compiler Version" in the "Build settings" of project